# performance with left join and include max in the query with values null

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data of the table exceeds 7 billion.
I want to display the max of entryDate affiliation for each participant and i want to include the null values so i used left join but the query takes long minute. Anyway it gives me the expected results.
Could anyone has a better idea or another better solution to fix the performance?

```
Select ParticipantID,MaxDate
    From dbo.Participant Par
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Affiliation Aff
    ON AFF.ParticipantID=Par.ParticipantID
    LEFT JOIN (
                               SELECT              AFF.AffiliationID,
                                                      MAX(EntryDate) as MaxDate
                               FROM                dbo.Affiliation

                               GROUP BY            AFF.AffiliationID

                    )AS AFF1
           ON           AFF1.AffiliationID = AFF.AffiliationID
                        AND AFF1.MaxDate = AFF.EntryDate
```

Comment: i am using SQL Server version 2014

Comment: You want to display 7 billion records and wonder why it takes "long minute"? How is this surprising?

Comment: @@Thorsten Kettner , No i do not want to display all but the max of non null values and including the null values . I could only use inner join with the max but I need the Participant who have EntryDate null also

Comment: Are you sure about SELECT              AFF.AffiliationID,
                                                      MAX(EntryDate) as MaxDate
                               FROM                dbo.Affiliation

                               GROUP BY            AFF.AffiliationID  ?       Is AffiliationID the PK of table Affiliation?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first join is unnecessary

```
SELECT ParticipantID, MaxDate
FROM dbo.Participant Par
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(EntryDate) as MaxDate
    FROM dbo.Affiliation Aff
    WHERE Aff.ParticipantID = ParParticipantID
) A
```

Also you need index on `Affilation`:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Affiliation_ParticipantID_EntryDate ON dbo.Affiliation(ParticipantID, EntryDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

@llyas There could be lot more considerations if you have xml show plan on or include actual execution plan and check for subtree cost

Anyways, you can use this query by using row_num function

```
WITH par
AS (
    SELECT ParticipantID
        ,EntryDate AS MaxDate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY AffiliationID ORDER BY ENTRYDATE DESC
            ) rn
    FROM dbo.Participant Par
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Affiliation Aff
        ON AFF.ParticipantID = Par.ParticipantID
    )
SELECT Participantid
    ,Maxdate
WHERE rn = 1
```